# Execute function after every post request

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Using Axios is there a way to "hook" a function to every post request?

I have a 'notification' module in `Vue.js` store, which stores API responses, so I need to call an `updateResponse` method in every post request `.then`

Comment: Why don't you just create a Vue component for this?

Comment: I have multiple components from which I dispatch an action involving a post request,  after these actions I always have to commit the same mutation which updates the API response stored in Vuex store. The API response is then displayed in a component. What I'm trying to do is: instead of explicitly writing the 'updateResponse' mutation call under every axios.POST, "hook" it to every post request once

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [Axios interceptors](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors)

```js
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    // Any status code that lie within the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
    // Do something with response data
    return response;
  }, function (error) {
    // Any status codes that falls outside the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
    // Do something with response error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
```

Comment: Is there a way to restrict interceptors only to specific HTTP methods ? (in my case, everything but GET methods)

Comment: No, you need to implement that yourself. ['response' variable](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema) has `request` key so you can use that to detect POST requests...

Answer (score 0):

You can add an interceptor to your vue.js app

So you can catch every post response before they get to `.then()` function

```
window.intercepted.$on('response', data => {
        console.log(data); // { status: 404, code: 'Not found', body: null }

        // Display the message.
    });
```

You may find more about it in vue-axios-interceptors package [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-axios-interceptors)

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do it without a package